# "." on numPad no longer centers view on selected

Tags: interface

<kbd>Numpad .</kbd> no longer centers the view on the *Selected Object*, but on the *Cursor*. I must have changed something in the settings unwittingly. Does anybody know how to reset it?

Comment: perhaps you've centered the view so many times that your numpad is wearing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure numlock is activated on your numeric keypad.

Numeric keypad have different flavors as well.
I have two numeric keypads attached.

Comment: Stupid me, I incidentally checked the "lock to cursor" box in the properties shelf.

Comment: Hmmm.  That probably wont make even the 99 most irritating and time consuming errors yet to come.  You got lucky!

Answer (score 0):

**TavernSenses** Thank you!
Your mistake help me to find my mistake, it was the same! Somehow I made that lock with: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (*View Lock to Active*), which centers the view to the last selected active object, overriding other view alignment settings.